# Skipping validation on tab out when a button is clicked

Tags: jquery, html, forms, jquery-validate

I am validating the fields of a form on tab out as well as validating the form itself when clicking on Submit button.I am using Jquery validator plugin.I have another button on the form,I use to go back to the list.When I click on 'Back to List' button,first field gets validated and I get the error message and I have to click on 'Back to List' again to cancel the creation.Now,I think this because I am validating on blur.Any ideas on how to circumvent this.

HTML is

```
   <div class="form-group text-center">
            <button type="submit" id="Submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
            <button type="reset" id="Reset" data-bind="click: reset" class="btn btn-primary">Reset</button>
            <a id="BacktoIndex" href="/Provider/ShowTheListOfProviders" class="btn btn-primary cancel">Back to List</a>
        </div>
```

JQUERY validation code is

```
 $("#providerDetailsForm").validate({
    onfocusout: function (element, event) {
        this.element(element);
    },
    onkeyup: function (element, event) {
        if (event.which === 9 && this.elementValue(element) === '') {
            return;
        } else if (element.name in this.submitted) {
            this.element(element);
        }
    },
    rules:
        {
            contactNumber: { required: true, minlength: 10, maxlength: 10 },
            contactEmail: { required: true, acceptEmail: true }
        },
    messages: {
        contactNumber: {
            required: "Please enter the Contact Number",
            minlength: "Minimum of 10 digits required.",
            maxlength: "Maximum of 10 digits allowed."
        },
        contactEmail: {
            required: "Please enter the Email Address",
            acceptEmail: "Please enter a valid email ID"
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Put `class="cancel"` on any `submit` button and validation will be skipped.

Comment: The 'BacktoLIst' button is not a Submit button,so might not work.

Comment: If the `BacktoLIst` button is not a `submit` button, then the jQuery Validate plugin can not possibly be validating anything based on its click.

Comment: Its because I am validating on tabout I think.

Comment: It works just fine, if I comment out that particular code.

Comment: That's because `onkeyup` and  `onfocusout` are already the default behaviors of the plugin, which happen under certain conditions (called "lazy" validation).  You've broken the built-in "lazy" validation by using your custom `onfocusout` and `onkeyup` functions.

Comment: It does not validate on tab out by default.Hence I had to specifically add that bit of code to validate on tabout.

Comment: ***Yes, it does*.  Again, it's called "lazy" validation**, which means that most validation triggers are ignored until after the `submit` button is clicked the first time.  [See bullet point #2 in the documentation here](http://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/#link-a-few-things-to-look-out-for-when-playing-around-with-the-demo).

Comment: Yes,you are correct.It does validate after I click on Submit.But I need the validation to happen on Tabout.So,I cant really comment that code out.What can be done to get around this issue?

Comment: It's doing exactly what you're telling it to do. How do you expect to click a button without focusing away from the current element? Meanwhile, try my original suggestion. A `type="submit"` button with `class="cancel"` will ignore all validation rules.

Comment: Your original suggestion unfortunately does not help me.I need to redirect to another page without validation.Your suggestion talks about Submitting a form without validation.Also my button type is not Submit and its an anchor tag.So,I cant really relate to your suggestion.

Comment: You can't simply change it to `type="submit"` ??  I don't see how that stops you from redirecting to whatever page you want.   Otherwise, I don't think anybody is going to be able to help you.  You need to focus on the button when you click it.  How do you think you can focus on the button _without_ also focusing _away_ from the last input element thus triggering validation.  Sorry, you will be stuck.